# Hot to access detailed variable information in tagged template literals like property name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tagged-templates

If I have a function that returns a tagged template literal I can console log the function toString() and it will show me the object and property name of my variable.

```
function myfN() {
 return tag`Test ${data.name}`
}
    
// this console logs the information I would need inside my tag, see below.
console.log(myfN.toString())
```

```
console output >>>>
function myfN() {
 return tag(_templateObject || (_templateObject = (0, _taggedTemplateLiteral2["default"])(["Test ", ""])), data.name);
}
```

as you can see `data.name` is in the log result, now when we look inside my tag function I have my strings and values

```
function tag(literals, ...vars) {
  console.log(literals.raw);
  console.log(vars);

  // get here that the literals are using `data.name`
}
```

Is there any way to get the variable names inside my tag without passing the whole object as a value into the string?
Everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with other functions, you can't access variable name that is used to pass data into it. There also may be no variable at all:

```js
tag`Test ${"look, ma! No variables!"}`
```

Only way to get variable name (if there any) and use it would be parsing and manipulating code, for example with babel.